# Crystal Reports to PDF not working or too slow

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I am trying to export a Crystal Report to PDF, however it is hanging on the export (several minutes) with no luck. When I use a blank report, it works fine, however when I use a custom report this problem occurs. Here is the code snippet:

```
Dim CrExportOptions As ExportOptions
Dim CrDiskFileDestinationOptions As New  _
DiskFileDestinationOptions()
Dim CrFormatTypeOptions As New PdfRtfWordFormatOptions()
CrDiskFileDestinationOptions.DiskFileName = Path.GetTempPath() +"Report.pdf"
CrExportOptions = report.ExportOptions
With CrExportOptions
     .ExportDestinationType = ExportDestinationType.DiskFile
     .ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat
     .DestinationOptions = CrDiskFileDestinationOptions
     .FormatOptions = New PdfRtfWordFormatOptions

End With

report.Export() 
Console.WriteLine("Done")
```

The form freezes once it reaches report.Export(). Here is the console output:

```
'FormName.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'
'FormName.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities\12.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.dll'
'FormName.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Windows.Forms\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Windows.Forms.dll'
'FormName.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll'
'FormName.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll'
'FormName.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.Sync\12.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.Sync.dll'
'FormName.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime\12.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.dll'
'FormName.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Users\sysmgr\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\FormName\FormName\bin\Debug\FormName.vshost.exe'
'FormName.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine\13.0.2000.0__692fbea5521e1304\CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.dll'
'FormName.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\CrystalDecisions.ReportSource\13.0.2000.0__692fbea5521e1304\CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.dll'
'FormName.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\CrystalDecisions.Shared\13.0.2000.0__692fbea5521e1304\CrystalDecisions.Shared.dll'
'FormName.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll'
'FormName.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll'
'FormName.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Deployment\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Deployment.dll'
'FormName.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll'
'FormName.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml.Linq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.Linq.dll'
'FormName.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.DataSetExtensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll'
'FormName.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualBasic\v4.0_10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll'
The thread 'vshost.NotifyLoad' (0x1428) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x288c) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'vshost.LoadReference' (0x510) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'FormName.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Users\sysmgr\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\FormName\FormName\bin\Debug\FormName.exe', Symbols loaded.
'FormName.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll'
'FormName.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Remoting\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.Remoting.dll'
'FormName.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_64\CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CommLayer\13.0.2000.0__692fbea5521e1304\CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CommLayer.dll'
'FormName.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_64\CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc\13.0.2000.0__692fbea5521e1304\CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc.dll'
'FormName.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_64\CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel\13.0.2000.0__692fbea5521e1304\CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel.dll'
'FormName.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_64\CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CubeDefModel\13.0.2000.0__692fbea5521e1304\CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CubeDefModel.dll'
'FormName.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_64\CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportDefModel\13.0.2000.0__692fbea5521e1304\CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportDefModel.dll'
'FormName.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_64\CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers\13.0.2000.0__692fbea5521e1304\CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers.dll'
'FormName.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataSetConversion\13.0.2000.0__692fbea5521e1304\CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataSetConversion.dll'
'FormName.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\System.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.dll'
'FormName.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_64\log4net\1.2.10.0__692fbea5521e1304\log4net.dll'
'FormName.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\CustomMarshalers\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\CustomMarshalers.dll'
'FormName.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\System.Transactions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Transactions.dll'
'FormName.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\System.EnterpriseServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.dll'
'FormName.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\System.EnterpriseServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll'
'FormName.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Numerics\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Numerics.dll'
'FormName.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_64\CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.XmlSerialize\13.0.2000.0__692fbea5521e1304\CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.XmlSerialize.dll'
'FormName.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Services\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.Services.dll'
'FormName.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_64\CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CommonObjectModel\13.0.2000.0__692fbea5521e1304\CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CommonObjectModel.dll'
```

After that it keeps writing the following

```
 The thread '<No Name>' (-thread code-) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

UPDATE: After a while, I get the following error:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.dll

Answer (score 0):

This might be to do with a windows update.  check for KB3102429, and remove it if present then try the pdf export again.

I had a similar issue, and remving the update solved the problem.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/3102429